# Can't get Custom Class working in SpriteKit Scene (swift & xcode7 beta)

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, xcode7

I am not sure if it is a bug or not, but even when I set a Custom Class name on one of the Sprite, it seems to be completely ignored.

[image]

I tried with a dragged asset, and then with a empty node, both completely ignores the Monkey class association and just create a raw SKSpriteNode.

The Monkey Node code is as follow.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Monkey: SKSpriteNode{

    let monkeyWalkAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "MonkeyWalk")

    override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: NSColor, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
        print("Monkey.init debug")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Note: Custom class on .sks node are new in xcode7.

### Edited June 21st 2015

I simplified the setup, but still the issue whe compiling/running in the iOS9 simulator. I created a project with the default SpriteKit template, chnage the GameSence to just have the following (and the empty Monkey class)

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touch down")
       /* Called when a touch begins */
        for node in self.children {
            print(node)
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}

public class Monkey: SKSpriteNode {}
```

Dragged an Empty node on the GameScene.sks, set the custom class to Monkey, but when I touch down to print the sub nodes, I get again:

```
touch down
<SKSpriteNode> name:'SKNode_0' texture:['nil'] position:{753.5, 333.5} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{0, 0} anchor:{0, 0} rotation:0.00
```

Comment: I fear this might not be working right for Swift namespaced class names. Have you tried it with a ObjC class (or a Swift class with an `@objc(name)` name)? Either way, it's probably worth [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Thank you @rickster, but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Haven't bumped up to xcode7, but it might be that you haven't implemented the init( coder: ) method.  Presumably, anything you modify in the Xcode builder would be using the coder init method to do its work, so if you haven't implemented it, it wouldn't be able to work with it.

Comment: @cc. I think I just did above, no?

Comment: You did, but it wouldn't return a usable object.  If Xcode uses coders to save the object and then re-load it, your object can't participate because it fatalErrors()'s its way out of it.

Comment: @cc. Thank you for the clarification. Still new in XCode and such. So, I have done it as updated above, but still the issue.

Comment: Sorry to hear that doesn't resolve your issue.  Still, it's probably a good thing that you did a "proper" implementation of init(coder:).  Even if something else is causing your issue, a correct implementation of init(coder:) will probably still be required.

Comment: I cannot reproduce; I made an empty `class Monkey: SKSpriteNode {}`, created a scene, added an empty node, linked it and then instantiated it with this code: `let c = SKScene(fileNamed: "MyScene")!; print(c.children.first! as! Monkey)`. This did not crash. Have you tried cleaning the project? Creating a new scene, class? Remember to first create the class before you try to link it. Xcode needs an existing class to successfully link.

Comment: @vrwim first, thank you so much for looking at it. I tried exactly what you did, started from scratch, have get the cast error. Here is the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/8xe0a2ih4c6u6ir/test-custom-class-sprite.zip?dl=0

Comment: @vrwim What version of iOS is the device/simulator you tested it on running?

Comment: Tried it on the simulator (iOS 9); will try to run on my device (iOS 8.3) when I get home

Comment: Ha, I was on osx, that might be the reason. I will give it a shot on iOS9

Comment: I think I got it, you need iOS 9/ OS X El Capitan or higher for this to work. Custom classes for sprites don't seem to be supported below that.

Comment: @vrwim Do you mean I need OSX El Captain even if a compile and run on the iOS9 simulator? This would make sense, because, I just tried with a new iOS9 project, and still no luck. Anyway, thank you for looking into this.

Comment: Nope, I am running latest version of Yosemite and it works on the iOS 9 sim. You might want to file a bug as @rickster mentioned.

Comment: @vrwim So, I found my problem when on iOS9 simulator. My project name had '-' in it, so, somehow it could not instantiate the class or something because the project name seems to be used as some sort of named spaced. Anyway, I created a new project name, without the '-' (jc09ios) and it workd. Doing a print(node.dynamicType) printed "jc07ios.Monkey". I finally get my monkey back! Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: I filed a bug report, and Apple said today they fixed it in the latest beta.  Downloading it right now...

Comment: @NobodyNada I just downloaded the new beta, and still have the problem when project name is "-". Works when you rename the project to avoid the "-" char.

Comment: But my project doesn't have a - in it.  (It has a space though.)

Comment: @NobodyNada I filed a bus with about the "-" #21528253 Anyway, right now, I am removing all my "-" on project names.

Comment: I upgraded to the beta and still have the bug.  I'll try removing the space from my project name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81456/discussion-between-nobodynada-and-jeremy-chone).

Answer (score 6):

In Swift you always have to add the module name before the class name. You can find the module name in the build settings in the field "Product Module Name".
If you use a "-" in your project name the module name converts the "-" to a "_".(In my test project called "Test-Game" the module name is "Test_Game" so I would have to use the "Test_Game.Monkey" as a custom class which works for me in the current Xcode Beta)

Comment: This worked for me! Be sure to check the Module name as spaces and some characters will be changed as suggested above with the "-" and "_".

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is having this problem with newer versions of XCode: @Nightmare_82's solution is correct, but Product Module Name is no longer an available setting. Later versions of XCode use Product Name as the Module Name. I had development builds with my  Product Name set to "My App (Dev)" and I switched it to "My App Dev" and all is well.